# Two one-to-one relations to the same table on Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I would like to map something like this:

```
public class FooPair
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Foo Foo1 { get; set; }
    public Foo Foo2 { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public FooPair Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And my DbContext:

```
public class FooContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FooPair> Pairs { get; set; }
}
```

EF is complaining it's unable to determine the relationship represented by the `Parent` navigation property.

The only solution I could think of, is to create two new inherited classes fom `Foo`, then EF will map them to their own tables and I get two 1-to-1 relations, but this doesn't feel right.

What would be the correct way of modeling such situation?

Comment: Why do you want to use two one-to-one relation on one table? I don't understand the situation. You can make it using one-to-many relation with manual restrictions on your code side am i right?

Comment: @kizilsu Yes, that's what I need. But since I'm new to EF I decided to ask because maybe there's a way to restrain this through the schema then I wouldn't need to worry about it in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below code help to solve your problem.
 refer [Eftutorials](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) for more details.

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual FooPair FooPair { get; set; }
}

public class FooPair
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id { get; set; }   
   public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

   public Foo()
    {
        Foos = new List<Foo>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using EF Code First you can do that like this

> It is recommended to include foreign key property in an entity class.
>   For example, if Foo entity includes FooPairId property which
>   automatically becomes foreignkey property because it follows the
>   convention for foreignkey < Type Name >Id.

[Here you find tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

```
public class FooPair
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Foo Foo1 { get; set; }
    public Foo Foo2 { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        FooPairs = new List<FooPair>();
    }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FooPairId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FooPairId")]
    public ICollection<FooPair> FooPairs { get; set; }
}
```